# Deploying Azure Stack at Amazon AWS

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services

just want to ask, if anyone faced to deploying Azure Stack into Amazon AWS.

Because of very specific reason in very specific country with very specific customer, we can not use Azure services in this country. But customer is ok with using Amazon AWS.

So the idea is to deploy Azure Stack into Amazon AWS to avoid rewriting whole app.

Do you ever even heard about this? Is it possible? What difficulties can arise?

Comment: that also very much depends upon what parts of azure services are you using and is that reason applicable to all the azure services and a specific few?

Comment: @ParvSharma the question is specifically with regards to Microsoft's [Azure in your datacenter](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-stack/) product, rather than an individual Azure Service..

Comment: @ParvSharma at less we need: Redis Cache, SQL, Storage, Virtual Machines vs Nice to have: DNS, Container and Cloud Services, but this is probably not the clue, because we really need stack as it is. (App is integrated into common Azure cloud already)

Comment: This may now be possible with the new i3.metal instances. See https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/05/announcing-general-availability-of-amazon-ec2-bare-metal-instances/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to deploy Azure Stack onto Amazon AWS because one of the [Requirements](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/server-cloud/2015/12/21/microsoft-azure-stack-hardware-requirements/) is [SLAT support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Level_Address_Translation) which is a form of hardware virtualisation.

The basic premise of Azure Stack is that you have a bunch of Hyper-v servers that emulate the Azure Cloud. The hardware that you use to create the Hyper-v servers needs specific capabilities in the underlying processor (basically to do with how resources are allocated, allowing the hypervisor to give direct access to hardware resources rather than emulating them, which is very processor intensive)

While it is entirely possible to have nested hypervisors (that is a hypervisor running within a hypervisor) AWS intentionally disable the processor capabilities that allow it, so that you cannot run a hypervisor within their EC2 instances. This is a business (and perhaps technical) decision on Amazon's part (and every other cloud operator)

Comment: Note that Azure v3 VMs now support nested hypervisors such as Hyper-V. Not sure about AWS in that regard.

Comment: This is no longer accurate; AWS supports Hyper-V instances with i3.metal (bare metal) EC2 instance types.

Comment: Just wondering if Bare Metal ec2 instances can be a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Stack Development Kit in theory can be run on AWS Bare Metal (i3.metal) instances.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-hyper-v-on-amazon-ec2-bare-metal-instances/

In practice, Microsoft only supports certified hardware configurations for production Azure Stack, and AWS is not currently one of them.